# Discretionary macro doesn't work with microtype and Adobe Garamond Pro in LuaLaTeX

Tags: fonts, luatex, letterspacing, discretionary

I've run into a problem with the combination of microtype package (v2.6a), LuaLaTeX (Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015) (rev 5238)) and Adobe Garamond Pro font, when macro `\discretionary` doesn't work within `\textls`. See the examples:

```
%%%! LuaLaTeX
\documentclass{book}
\def\fontBaseName{adobegaramondpro}
\def\fontBaseNameBold{agaramondprosemibold}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX,Common}}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\setmainfont[BoldFont={\fontBaseNameBold}]{\fontBaseName}
\usepackage[tracking = true]{microtype}
\begin{document}
\def\={\discretionary{-}{-}{-}}

není\=li

\textls{není\=li}
\end{document}
```

produces this defective result:

[image]

whereas with `\setmainfont` command commented out (i.e. using the default font) the `\discretionary` macro works:

[image]

Any help appreciated.

**Edit:** Apparently it isn't related to microtype — when I comment this package out completely and use e.g.:

```
\defaultfontfeatures{ItalicFeatures={LetterSpace=2}}
...
\textit{není\=li} % common italic, nothing from microtype
```

the error (missing hyphen) occurs as well. Without `\defaultfontfeatures` or without Garamond it works just fine, however **Garamond** plus **letter spacing** equals problem.

Comment: Any chance of upgrading to TeXLive2016 (LuaTeX 0.95)? The reason I ask is that your MWE runs correctly on my system (MacTeX2016/ LuaTex 0.95, microtype v.2.6a).

Comment: @Mico: This is a project I am working on over a year, and I tried TL2016 sometime in June or so and had some other problems (don't remember what however). Nevertheless this is a strong inducement, so if no solution comes out from here I'll certainly give it another try. Thx.

Comment: Have you tried TL16? Anything new?

Comment: @TeXnician Seems to be working fine with TL16.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by using a currently stable distribution (TL2016).